# Efficiently iterate and mutate an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, ruby-on-rails-5

We have code that is effectively doing this.

```
obj.things.each |thing|
    ... do some stuff ...

    obj.things.destroy(thing)

    ... do some more stuff...
end
```

We found out that simultaneously iterating over a CollectionProxy while changing the CollectionProxy results in only half the items being iterated over. Currently we're working around this by flattening the proxy into an array. But this means copying all the `things` into memory.

```
obj.things.to_a.each |thing|
    ...
end
```

Is there a way to iterate and mutate through a collection without pulling the entire association into memory?

Alternatively, is there a better pattern than the one we're using? For example, the wrapping code are things we don't want to do every time we destroy an association, so we're not using association hooks. Could we write a subclass or scope that can use hooks?

***UPDATE***: [I've posted about the larger issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434318/consistently-using-associated-model-subclasses).

Answer (score 1):

Destroying the object inside the look is actually a bad practice.

I can think of two methods, you could save the ids of the objects you want to destroy on an array or mark them on the database to be deleted (adding a new boolean column defaulted to false and do `update_column :to_destroy, true`).

That way you can do Thing.where(id: ids_to_destroy).destroy_all (or something like Thing.where(to_destroy: true).destroy_all if you marked them) after the loop.

What method to use depends on your needs. I would go with saving the ids on an array since it need less changes, but maybe you process a really big amount of data and saving a really really big array on memory is too much (not a common case since you are just storing ids, but it is possible though).

Comment: If you save the ids to an array as you iterate then you don't even need to look them back up, you could just use `obj.things.destroy(*ids_to_delete_array)` since [`CollectionProxy#destroy`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-destroy) can take multiple arguments

Comment: If you pass ids to 'destroy' it dose the same thing. Records need to be instantiated because ActiveRecord calls 'destroy' on each one. Personally I prefer 'where(...).destroy_all'.

Comment: [I've posted about the larger issue which lead to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434318/consistently-using-associated-model-subclasses). I'd appreciate it if you could have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Your original `each` is already pulling the entire association into memory.

Calling `to_a` to produce an extra copy of the array (which is then free of mutation) is indeed a very reasonable approach. And not particularly expensive: the array is duplicated, but the actual objects are not.

You could also use [`ActiveRecord::Base#destroy`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy) instead:

```
obj.things.each |thing|
    ... do some stuff ...

    thing.destroy

    ... do some more stuff...
end
```

As the `obj.things` collection is no longer aware of the destruction, it will still contain the full set of things, and thus the iteration will be unaffected. (This could obviously be problematic if either `stuff` block is using the current contents of `obj.things`, though.)

Comment: That's good to know that only the Array is duplicated, thank you. The actual situation is a bit more complicated as the `each` loop is really calling a method which is doing more work and then calling `obj.things.destroy` to ensure the collection remains up to date.

Comment: [I've posted about the larger issue which lead to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434318/consistently-using-associated-model-subclasses). I'd appreciate it if you could have a look.

Comment: @Schwern you can ensure the collection remains up to date calling `obj.reload` after the each block. As arieljuod said in the other answer, remove the object from the collection inside the collection loop block is a bad practise.

Comment: @DanielBatalla Yes, I'd prefer to make use of `destroy_all`.